# Changing HTML and CSS files don't show the change on the Apache virtual host?

Tags: html, apache, css, virtualhost, localhost

I've been working on a website and I'm testing it on a virtual server hosted by my desktop.

Whenever I change something on the HTML or CSS file I'm in, it shows the change I did on the LiveServer (the VSCode extension one), but it doesn't update the change on the Apache Server.
I've restarted the server multiple times, but it just doesn't show the change on it.
What am I doing wrong?

```css
.u-section-1 .u-image-2 {
  background-image: url("images/2020-10-01\ 16.13.00.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 2.73%;
  min-height: 294px;
}
```

I changed the `url("images/2020-...);` part to an existing image in the HTML file, but it doesn't change when I view the page.

Comment: Maybe LiveServer and Apache are conflicting? Are you editing the correct file? Are you browsing with caching disabled (ie. open dev tools and "disable cache" on the network tab)?

Comment: @awakuruf  Did the answer below work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that browser is caching it.

On most browsers, `Ctrl+F5` will refresh the page.

For major changes it is better to clear all caches.  On Chrome the command is

```
Ctrl+Shift+Del.
```